# How could I know if all processes have been already created before sending signals?

Tags: c

I'm writing a Unix program where the parent process has to send signals to children and a grandson. How could I know if all processes have been already created before sending signals? Because sometimes they don't exist yet. Thanks a lot!

```
void t(int sig)
{
   kill(SIGKILL, pidc1);
   kill(SIGKILL, pidc2);
   kill(SIGKILL, pidg2);
   kill(SIGKILL, pidc3);
}

void handler()
{
    write(1, "Signal SIGUSR1\n", 15);
}

pid_t pidc1, pidc2, pidc3, pidg2;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sigaction action;
    int status;

    action.sa_flags = 0;
    action.sa_handler = handler;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &action, NULL);

    pidc1 = fork();
    if(pidc1 == 0)
    {
        printf("Child 1\n");
    }
    pidc2 = fork();
    if(pidc2 == 0)
    {
         printf("Child 2\n");
         pidg2 = fork();
         if(pidg2 == 0)
         {
             printf("Grandson 2\n");
         }
         wait(&status);
    }
    pidc3 = fork();
    if(pidc3 == 0)
    {
        printf("Child 3\n");
    }

    kill(pidg2, SIGUSR1);
    kill(pidc3, SIGUSR1);
    signal(SIGALRM, t);
    alarm(10);
    wait(&status);
}
```

Comment: How do you detect the process doesn't exist yet? There is no error handling in your code.

Comment: Sometimes or always? `pidg2` will always be 0 in the parent process for example.

Comment: I mean always. All processes have to be created before sending signals.

Comment: If you need to wait for the grandchild processes to be created, you need some kind of communication from the child to the parent, so it can send the grandchild's PID. Shared memory and a mutex would be a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Preliminary note: The child code parts in your example program fall through to their parent's code, which is certainly not intended; I'll assume something like `return sleep(5);` at the end of each block. Also note that the `printf()`s may malfunction with `fork()`s and buffered output.

Barmar wrote:

> If you need to wait for the grandchild processes to be created, you need some kind of communication from the child to the parent, so it can send the grandchild's PID. Shared memory and a mutex would be a way to do this.

That's absolutely correct. (The direct children are no problem, since the parent knows their PIDs.) Another way to communicate the grandchild's PID is a pipe; your example `main()` could become:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int status;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &(struct sigaction){.sa_handler = handler}, NULL);
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);   // printf() may malfunction without this
    pidc1 = fork();
    if (pidc1 == 0)
    {
        printf("Child 1\n");    return sleep(5);
    }
    int pipefd[2];
    pipe(pipefd);   // for communicating the grandson's PID
    pidc2 = fork();
    if (pidc2 == 0)
    {
         printf("Child 2\n");
         pidg2 = fork();
         if (pidg2 == 0)
         {
             printf("Grandson 2\n");   return sleep(5);
         }
         write(pipefd[1], &pidg2, sizeof pidg2);    // write pidg2 to write end
         wait(&status);    return sleep(5);
    }
    pidc3 = fork();
    if(pidc3 == 0)
    {
        printf("Child 3\n");    return sleep(5);
    }
    read(pipefd[0], &pidg2, sizeof pidg2);  // read pidg2 from pipe's read end
    kill(pidg2, SIGUSR1);
    kill(pidc3, SIGUSR1);
}
```